# How to assign arrow function return value to string[] in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have the following cast issue with the typescript code below:

**Error:**

*Type '() => string[]' is missing the following properties from type 'string[]': pop, push, concat, join, and 24 more.
function stringArray(): string[]*

```
function stringArray(): string[] {

    return ['a', 'b', 'c']
}

let a: string[]

a = (): string[] => stringArray()
```

I simplified the code so nobody has to understand the actual problem I'm trying to solve. The main question is how can I define the return value of the arrow function to be accepted for the assignment of `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are assigning an arrow function reference in the variable `a`.

```
function stringArray(): string[] {

    return ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}

let a: Function;

a = (): string[] => stringArray();
```

Instead you should set the type as `Function`

Or you can **invoke** the arrow function to return the array `['a', 'b', 'c']`:

```
function stringArray(): string[] {

    return ['a', 'b', 'c'];
}

let a: string[];

a = ((): string[] => stringArray())();
```

To make it simple:

```
 function stringArray(): string[] {

    return ['a', 'b', 'c'];
 }

 let a: string[];

 a = stringArray();
```

Comment: Pretty obvious! Now I'm feeling little stupid that I asked the question in the first place ...

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning another arrow function to a. To assign the return value to a, invoke the function in assignment.

```
let a: string[]
a = stringArray()
```